# GCC and Clang differ in static_assert related to __builtin_constant_p

Tags: c++, g++, constexpr, clang++, static-assert

I happen to find that GCC and Clang differ in the compilation of the following code:

```cpp
struct Foo
{
    int mem = 42;
};

int main()
{
    constexpr Foo foo;
    static_assert(__builtin_constant_p(foo));
    return 0;
}
```

I compile with `g++ -std=c++17` and `clang++ -std=c++17`.

In particular,

- g++ `g++-9 (Homebrew GCC 9.3.0_1) 9.3.0` compiles, whereas
- clang++ `Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)` fails to compile, complaining that

```
error: static_assert failed due to requirement '__builtin_constant_p(foo)'
    static_assert(__builtin_constant_p(foo));
    ^             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I didn't find any hint that there should be any difference regarding `__builtin_constant_p`.

For `__builtin_constant_p`

[GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) says

> You can use the built-in function __builtin_constant_p to determine if a value is known to be constant at compile time ...

[Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html)
says

> Clang supports a number of builtin library functions with the same syntax as GCC, including things like __builtin_nan, __builtin_constant_p, __builtin_choose_expr, __builtin_types_compatible_p, __builtin_assume_aligned, __sync_fetch_and_add, etc.

**Question:** While I know `__builtin_constant_p` is a compiler extension, which one should be the correct one?

Answer (score 1):

Both are poorly documented so I doubt there is a proper answer to your question.

If you need a workaround: it seems that clang gives up if the argument is not an int.

So this works:

```
struct Foo
{
    int mem = 42;
};

int main()
{
    constexpr Foo foo;
    static_assert(__builtin_constant_p(foo.mem));
    return 0;
}
```